# Sorcerous Blade Channeling Feat Trigger?

Tags: dnd-4e

If a creature had an effect trigger when they were hit with a melee attack and the sorcerer used acid orb using the sorcerous blade channeling feat, would the creature's ability trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

The feat says:

> you can use the power as a melee attack

If you do use it as a melee attack, it triggers responses as a melee attack.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted confirmation as I was arguing the above, but my DM thought otherwise.